# db2set codepage in not working in DB2 windows

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am using DB2 version 9.7 and 10.1 both.When i execute the command to change the code page like "db2set db2codepage=1250" it does not show any error. but aftre that when i import the data then it throws the following  error 
SQLCODE:  -332  -  SQLSTATE:  57017
***  SQL0332N  Character conversion from the source code page "1252" to the target code page "1250" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=57017

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005657.html "The user should not set DB2CODEPAGE unless explicitly stated in DB2 documents, or asked to do so by DB2 service." Why do you need to change it?

Comment: We need to load Data. Data is in  multilingual format. If we load data without setting proper codepage it insert junk characters. But when we set the code page data get inserted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

if the charset is utf-8 you should use DB2CODEPAGE=1208 on non-windows and 1252 on windows in the system and restart your application.